# Converção de imgens em PDF com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando converter todas as imagens de um diretório, em um único PDF. Porém estou com dificuldades.

Quando executo meu sistema ele da o erro abaixo, ele tenta ler o arquivo .py também.

```
from PIL import Image
import os
filepath = os.getcwd()

for p in os.listdir(filepath):

    filename = filepath+'\\'+p

    im = Image.open(filename)

    if im.mode == "RGB":
        im = im.convert("RGB")
    new_file = "novo.pdf"
    new_filename = os.getcwd()
    file = new_filename+"\\"+new_file
    if not os.path.exists(new_filename):
        im.save(file, "PDF")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "C:/crl/pdf/teste.py", line 9, 
   in <module> im = Image.open(filename) 
 File "C:\Users\willian.angelo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2687, 
   in open % (filename if filename else fp)) OSError: cannot identify image file 'C:\\crl\\pdf\\teste.py'
```

Comment: Cara, colocar o erro que ta acontecendo. Qual a sua duvida, pq ficou muito vago

Comment: Me desculpe me esqueci de colocar o erro!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/crl/pdf/teste.py", line 9, in <module>
    im = Image.open(filename)
  File "C:\Users\willian.angelo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2687, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file 'C:\\crl\\pdf\\teste.py'

Comment: esse arquivo .py esta no mesmo diretório das imagens, você pode remover as imagens para outro diretório

Comment: este arquivo .py é o proprio scripit python, eu até posso colocar as imgaens em outra pasta, porém eu quero que o scritp rode no diretório atual, pois vou adicionar aos recursos do Sistema operacional, para ser utilizado de forma rapida

Answer (score 0):

você pode checar se o arquivo termina com `.py` e ignorar ele, utilizando uma condição com a função `endswith` da classe `string`. Conforme exemplo abaixo. Seria uma das opções.

```
from PIL import Image
import os
filepath = os.getcwd()

for p in os.listdir(filepath):
    if not str(p).endswith('.py'):

        filename = filepath+'\\'+p

        im = Image.open(filename)

        if im.mode == "RGB":
            im = im.convert("RGB")
        new_file = "novo.pdf"
        new_filename = os.getcwd()
        file = new_filename+"\\"+new_file
        if not os.path.exists(new_filename):
            im.save(file, "PDF")
```